# How can I recall awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to recall awakeFromNib when the tableView reload it's cells, to re-execuse the code I am executing there and newly load a pageViewController who is inside the cell, is that possible?

Comment: Not You should not call  awake from nib manually , you  can use prepareToReuse Method for cell

Comment: Maybe just put your code from `awakeFromNib` to function and execute function again?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `awakeFromNib` is called on an object when it is initialized from a nib file. So you can not call it manually.

Read this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW18) for object loading process from nib file.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation from apple about `awakeFromNIb` method

> After all objects have been instantiated and initialized, the
>   nib-loading code reestablishes the outlet and action connections for
>   all of those objects. It then calls the awakeFromNib method of the
>   objects.

So, calling it manually looks not possible. Moreover I suggest you to put the lines of code in `awakeFromNib` into a seperate method and call that method. It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As the other respondents point out, you should not call any of the "lifecycle" methods yourself. However, there is no reason on earth why you can't do something like:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.doSetupStuffINeedToRepeat()
}

func doSetupStuffINeedToRepeat() {
   //...
}
```

Then you can simply call `doSetupStuffINeedToRepeat()` anytime you want. The reason that you shouldn't call `awakeFromNib` yourself is that, if done properly, it should call `super.awakeFromNib`, and doing this in the middle of execution may (will) really mess things up...